# Angular 2 : AuthGard renders the page before it checks whether SecurityContext is applied or not

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, router

i'm working with a angular and i'm trying to apply some AuthGard on some Paths.

The problem is **canActivate()** renders the content before it checks with the SecurityContext, after a verification that no SecurityContext is applied then a redirection to the default page (login) page is applied.

This is the portion of code responsible for this.

---

**app.routing.ts**

```
    {
      path: 'admin',
      canActivate: [AuthGard],
      component: HomeComponent,
      children : [
        {
          path: 'add-merchant-admin',
          component : AddMerchantAdminComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'list-merchant-admin',
          component : ListMerchantAdminComponent,
        }
      ]
    },
```

---

**AuthGard.ts**

```
  canActivate(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    this._authService.getRoles().subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
          this.roles = JSON.parse(res.text());
          this.role = this.roles[0].authority;
          localStorage.setItem('role', this.role);
          if (this.role == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
            this._router.navigate(['admin']);
          } else {
            if (this.role == 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS') {
              this._router.navigate(['login']);
              this.error = false;
            }
          }
        } else {
          this._router.navigate(['login']);
          this.error = true;
        }
      }, err => {
        this._router.navigate(['login']);
        this.error = true;
      }
    );
    return !this.error;
  };
```

---

**AuthService**

```
  getRoles() {
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: true});
    return this.http.get('http://10.0.0.239:8080/**/**/RolesResource/getRole', options)
      .map((res) => res)
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.text() || 'Server error'));
  }
```

All Services are correctly injected, 
Normally a redirection to protected area or default page should be applied after the verification is made using **getRole()** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `this._authService.getRoles()` makes a network call which is asynchronous. `return !this.error;` is being fired before the network call is being returned so `!this.error` does not change and is therefore still truthy.

To solve this issue you should be able to return an observable as follows:

```
return this._authService.getRoles().map(
  res => {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      this.roles = JSON.parse(res.text());
      this.role = this.roles[0].authority;
      localStorage.setItem('role', this.role);
      if (this.role == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
        this._router.navigate(['admin']);
      } else {
        if (this.role == 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS') {
          this._router.navigate(['login']);
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
      return true;
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    this._router.navigate(['login']);
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
);
```

Comment: `Type Subscription is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable | Promise. Property then is missing in subscription.`

Comment: change yout type to just `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: `Type Subscription is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>. Property 'is_Scalar' is missing in subscription.`

Comment: sorry i made anouther update, got to return an observable, not one with a subscription. please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
canActivate(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this._authService.getRoles()
        .map(response => JSON.parse(response.text())[0].authority)
        .do(role => localStorage.setItem('role', role))
        .map( role => role === 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        .catch(() => this._router.navigate(['login']));
};
```

Comment: where is the navigation routing to admin page?

Comment: That's not really what a guard should do. A guard basically says: can I go there, yes or no.

Comment: if you go to https://angular.io/guide/router and search `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` you will see an example where they navigate directly in the canActivate method. I would say that this fair indication that a guard should do it

Comment: Yes, when a user isn't logged in, which completely makes sense. In to OPs example there isn't a successfull path. All options are redirecting to somewhere else. That is not what a guard is for.

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning `return !this.error;` which is always true, try to return

```
 canActivate(_route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, _state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this._authService.getRoles().map(
          res => {
            if (res.status == 200) {
              this.roles = JSON.parse(res.text());
              this.role = this.roles[0].authority;
              localStorage.setItem('role', this.role);
              if (this.role == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
                this._router.navigate(['admin']);
              } else {
                if (this.role == 'ROLE_ANONYMOUS') {
                  this._router.navigate(['login']);
                 return false;
                }
              }
            } else {
              this._router.navigate(['login']);
             return true;
            }
          }, err => {
            this._router.navigate(['login']);
            return Observable.of(false);
          }
        );
      };
```

Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can try with return observable, which can be updated either true or false.